# Tweepy will not respond to username but only string that is used. Any clue what I am doing wrong?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am trying to get this section of code to respond to the @ / username rather than the string that has to be used in order to get the latest reply.

```
for mention in reversed(mentions):
    if "@BotExampleName" in mention.full_text:
        last_Seen_id = mention.id
        store_id(last_Seen_id, FILE)
        api.update_status('@' + mention.user.screen_name + 'Bot reply successful', mention.id)
        print('Replied to @' + mention.user.screen_name)
```

Comment: Who is `BotExampleName`? Is it your Twitter bot? And how do you fetch the tweets you want to process?

Comment: @BeppeC BotExampleName is the name of the twitter bot. I just used it as the variable here when asking the question. I fetch the latest tweet with the tweet ID that is given to it. I then store in a .txt file. I can add the code for that if you need to see it. Thank you for your time!